# Multilevel Parent-Child records from one source file in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a Source file that contains parent child relationship records in multilevel.
Example:

```
ID  ParentID    Name
A1  NULL        Sam
B1  NULL        Sri
A2  A1      Nick
B2  B1      Sree
A3  A2      Nish
A4  A3      Raj
```

Explanation:

```
A1 --> A2 --> A3 --> A4

A1 --> Parent of A2
A2 -->Parent of A3
A3 --> Parent of A4

B1-->B2

B1 --> Parent of B2
```

Now I have to load these records into Destination table like below with Identity column.

```
ID  ParentID     Name
1   NULL        Sam
2   NULL        Sri
3   1       Nick
4   2       Sree
5   3       Nish
6   5       Raj
```

Now thing is that, There is no fixed level (How deep that relationship goes).

```
-   Is there any way to load in one go all records ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add additional columns to your destination table?

If so:

1. Add two columns `SourceId` and `SourceParentId` do your `Destination` table
2. During data flow store `NULL` in destination's `ParentID` and `ID` and `ParentID` from source in `SourceId` and `SourceParentId` respectively. After this step your Destination Table Should look similar to:

   ```
   ID  ParentID Name SourceId SourceParentId
   1   NULL     Sam  A1       NULL
   2   NULL     Sri  B1       NULL
   3   NULL     Nick A2       A1
   4   NULL     Sree A2       A1
   5   NULL     Nish A3       A2
   6   NULL     Raj  A4       A3
   ```
3. In `Execute SQL Task` execute on destination following SQL:

   ```
   update dest set [ParentID] = src.ID
   from [dbo].[Destination] dest inner join [dbo].[Destination] src 
   on dest.[SourceParentId] = src.[SourceId]
   ```

   which will update your `ParentID`.